# Best file format for text logo for use in Word, Web, PDF

Tags: logo, text, file-format

I have no previous knowledge in graphics *at all*. I decided to re-create our company logo using adobe illustrator since that's what everyone said would be best. I would use this logo on Microsoft Office and Word Perfect Documents that I would later print to Adobe PDF. I have messed around with several options but haven't figured out the right combo - mainly because I don't understand it all. I want to export my file to several different sizes and formats. PNG, JPEG.. will be used for web as well... I cant seem to smooth the edges of the text when the word (and word perfect) file is printed to PDF. It looks jagged and the left edge is cut off. What am I doing wrong?!
JPEG File:[image]

Prints to PDF from Word like this: 
[Test Logo w Word](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr6e2tee6160mwy/test%20logo%20w%20word.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: How did you make the .pdf? How did you bring the file into word? What are all of the settings? Its kinda hard for us to help without knowing all of the information.

Comment: I literally typed the words in illustrator to make a new logo. I have changed the settings around so much I don't even know anymore. I am learning the difference between vector and raster images now and I think this is where my problem is. Here is the original .ai image... https://www.dropbox.com/s/8e45rsc4v6ceyie/Stone%20LogoCAG%20Shadow.ai?dl=0
which I exported to a .png and also to a .jpg... i slapped the both the jpg and png on word docs and printed them to PDF. They both equally look terrible.

Comment: I saved this sucker as a JPG, PNG, DWG, Save for word, Save for web, I changed the 'document raster effect settings' down to 50 (from 71), checked anti-aliasing... I guess its looking a little better but still isn't perfect. My usual habit is to -print- my word docs to Adobe PDF but tried -save as- PDF which looks significantly better. There has got to be something with my save/export settings that is making it look terrible.

Answer (score 3):

- Open file in Illustrator
- Choose `File > Export`
- Select `PNG` from the format drop down
- Click `OK`
- Choose `High (300ppi)` from the **Resolution** drop down
- Choose `Type Optimized (Hinted)` from the **Anti-Aliasing** drop down
- Choose `Transparent` from the **Background** drop down
- Click `OK`
- Launch Word
- Open Word document
- Choose `Insert > Photo > Picture from File...`
- Select the PNG you just exported
- Choose `File > Save As...`
- Choose `PDF` from the **Format** drop down
- Click `OK`

Seems to work fine for me.

Microsoft products actually *prefer* png over jpg when possible.

Comment: depends on what you optimize for I would just embed a pdf or eps file

Comment: @joojaa PDF and EPS files can be very problematic, especially if the .doc file goes to a different machine. Yes they are *technically* supported. But the support is not exceptionally stable. In addition, you may need a postscript level 3 printer to properly support printing the embedded PDF/EPS image. PNG24 is honestly the most versatile, best supported, format for multiple users and multiple machines.

Comment: Also note the "Save for Microsoft Office" menu item in Illustrator... which generates a PNG24. :)

Comment: Yes I know but when generating pdf from word this creates a better file. Even having a 300 dpi image in word is dangerous as it dowsanples the thing. But depends on what you optimize PNG optimizes ease of use, not quality...

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my experience here in case it helps someone else, I know this issues is discussed all over the place as it is a common complaint/problem with Word.

I've never had luck with using either JPG or PNG in Word if my goal is crisp logo art in a PDF. Best way seems to be to use an EPS, and turn it into a PDF using something other than Word's save as PDF.

Here is an example of the same file printed to PDF using Bluebeam Revu PDF printer. Left is EPS, middle is a 100 quality, 300 dpi JPG, right is a 300 dpi transparent PNG. Word does not seem to care what resolution you export it from Illustrator as.

[image]

As other people have said though, Word's handling of EPS can be dodgy. If you use the built in Save As > PDF capability in Word, you'll end up with a disaster:

[image]

Also, if you just print straight from Word (rather than "printing" to a PDF and then printing that), then you're at the mercy of the printer and driver. We have some Xerox printers that will print the embedded EPS happily with the right colors (or close enough, we're not a print shop), but our Canon MFP prints the red color practically black.

I wish I knew more about how Word really handles different graphics formats though. With more and more businesses transmitting paperwork electronically, you really want your PDFs to look sharp and that's difficult to get out of Word easily.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Great contribution, thank you for including images and explaining your answer clearly. If you have any questions about the site check out the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest open the EPS file in Photoshop (anti-aliased, 300 ppi) then save as JPG at minimum compression.

This gave me the best results in comparison with the use of files in Word created by various methods of exporting from Illustrator.